# filtering two arrays one is NSArray(Core Data) and the other is NSMutableArray(simple)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am getting Core Data in to an array which consists of some records and am getting the locations distance (2.5 km)example  so i have to filter this two arrays with the distance

this is the code am doing now

Locations ...

```
locaFilterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int l = 0 ; l < dealArray.count; l++) {
    Deal * deal = (Deal *)dealArray[l];
    NSArray * locArray = [[deal locationRelation]allObjects];
    double minValue = 10000;
    if (locArray.count > 0) {
        for (int l = 0; l < locArray.count ; l++) {
            DealLocation * location = (DealLocation *)locArray[l];
            double latitude = [[location latitude]doubleValue];
            double longitude = [[location longitude]doubleValue];
            CLLocation * cdLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
            CLLocation * currLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:appDelegate.currentLatitude longitude:appDelegate.currentLongitude];
            CLLocationDistance distance = [currLocation distanceFromLocation:cdLotion]/1000;
            if (distance < minValue) {
                minValue = distance;
            }
        }
    } else {
        minValue = 5;
    }
    NSString * value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",minValue];
    [locaFilterArray addObject:value];
}
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)locaFilterArray.count);
```

in this way am getting printed like this ///  2.5 , 1.2 , 18.3 , 4.5.... like this

and from core data am getting the date so there is no relation between these two arrays but i have to filter this core data data to ascending order in the table view

any help will be great appreciations ... :)

Comment: Why do you not perform the filtering/sorting of the Core Data array during your fetch request?

Comment: yes i can do but  i know how to do but the value i have to use is not from core data

Comment: Which value? The value to filter by? If so, it doesn't matter, because you can provide a predicate and sort descriptors, and they are not related to Core Data.

Comment: okay the above code shows you it is printing in the format NSString i cannot filter in the form ascending right so how can i do that

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Use `NSSortDescriptor` and provide the key to sort by.

Comment: 2.5 , 1.2 , .... this are in the form of NSString and also this data in NSMutableArray

Comment: It's a number so use `NSNumber` instead.

Comment: we use predicate values to compare the values from one value to the Core Data value but there is no such value is stored in to the core data so how can i predicate the values

Comment: Okay tell me one thing how can i store the values in the form of NSNumber when the loop is running ....

Comment: Okay now am saving in the format of nsnumber that means now i have two arrays now 1 is with coredata 1 is with data like this 1.5 , 1.7 , 2.5 ... like this  so how can i filter data here